# Subdomain didn't send any data | ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE | Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to connect my Heroku App via a custom GoDaddy subdomain. The subdomain is "subdomain" (for the sake of example). What I'm doing is, copying the [DNS Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zv2t.jpg) from Heroku and [adding it in GoDaddy as a CNAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQpLH.jpg) such that it is pointing to the DNS Target given by Heroku. Nonetheless, I'm getting the following error when going to [www.subdomain.mysite.org](http://www.subdomain.mysite.org)

[image]

I have previously created subdomains and connected them to GoDaddy with the DNS Target that Heroku provides. Don't know what I'm doing wrong. I tried to refresh the DNS but it's not working.